# file.write only performed upon exit of an interactive python session?

Tags: python

I have discovered a behavior that I don't understand and was hoping someone could shed some light on it.

It looks like interactive python sessions (both with ipython and just calling the python3 cmd directly) only write to a file when I exit the session.

```
(ipython)dev:~$ ipython
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: outfile = open('outfile','w')

In [2]: outfile.write('test')
Out[2]: 4

In [3]: outfile.close
Out[3]: <function TextIOWrapper.close>

In [4]: !ls -l outfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jjk3 jjk3 0 Jun 10 14:32 outfile

In [5]: quit
(ipython)dev:~$ ls -l outfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jjk3 jjk3 4 Jun 10 14:33 outfile
(ipython)dev:~$
```

Is this behavior expected? If so why?

If this behavior is unexpected, any idea why it might be behaving this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not call close so the file is still open until you exit the shell:

```
outfile.close() # <- add parens
```

Once you do you can see the difference:

```
In [12]: outfile = open('outfile','w')    
In [13]:  outfile.write('test')    
In [14]:  outfile.close
Out[14]: <function close>    
In [15]: !ls -l outfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 padraic padraic 0 Jun 10 22:41 outfile    
In [16]:  outfile.close()
In [17]: !ls -l outfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 padraic padraic 4 Jun 10 22:41 outfile
```

You should use `with` to open your files and let it handle the closing for you:

```
In [18]: with open('outfile','w') as out:
   ....:     out.write("test")
   ....:        
In [19]: !ls -l outfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 padraic padraic 4 Jun 10 22:43 outfile
```

Comment: Ah, well crap. I spent way too long trying to figure out why it wasn't getting written. thanks.